# SyntaxError: Missing initializer in destructuring declaration

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I am running this on Node.js version 6.9.5

I have this code:

```
let {Schema}, mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

which is in theory a simplified version of:

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
let Schema = mongoose.Schema;
```

I get this error:

```
let {Schema}, mongoose = require('mongoose');
    ^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Missing initializer in destructuring declaration
```

I tried this instead:

```
let mongoose, {Schema} = require('mongoose');
```

I got a different error, which was the result of "mongoose" being undefined.

I thought it was possible to do something like this, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: No. `let {Schema}, mongoose = require('mongoose');` it's same as `let {Schema}; let mongoose = require('mongoose');` so it will not work. 
`let mongoose, {Schema} = require('mongoose');` it's same as `let mongoose; let {Schema} = require('mongoose');` so `mongoose` is really undefined.

Comment: thanks, can you add this as an answer, it's hard to read.

Comment: Sorry, I've added.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No.

`let {Schema}, mongoose = require('mongoose');`

it's same as

```
let {Schema};
let mongoose = require('mongoose');`
```

so it will not work because it's not exists object wherefrom take `Schema` .

`let mongoose, {Schema} = require('mongoose');`

it's same as

```
let mongoose;
let {Schema} = require('mongoose');`
```

And `mongoose` is really undefined.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was because I was returning empty variables so I had to check their values. Make sure you're returning the right data.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, that was because of the syntax. With `node v18.7.0` and with basic JS (not typescript), I should use (with your example):

```js
import mongoose, {Schema} = from 'mongoose';
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was missing an extra `}` at the end of useEffect